# how to check an array with cart price rule ID magento 2

Tags: blocks, collection, shopping-cart-price-rules, phtml, factory

I am trying to get Cart_Price_Rule.

```
   public function test()
{
    $ruleArray = $this->adventCollectionFactory->create()->getData();
    $ruleArray = array_column($ruleArray,'promo_rule_id');
    return implode($ruleArray);
}
```

This allows me to see the 2 rule id i have pased in a collection

But how would I check it with rule repository individually 
My results are 1 and 2
and I have a cart price rule which has the ID of 1 and 2 I am trying to grab the description and code in phtml

```
\Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleRepository $ruleRepository 
$rule = $this->ruleRepository->getById($this->test()); //how do i pass it individually the id's

$rule->getDescription();
$rule->getCondition();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function test(){

    $ruleArray = $this->adventCollectionFactory->create()->getData();
    $ruleArray = array_column($ruleArray,'promo_rule_id');
    $array=  implode($ruleArray);


    print_r($array);

}
```

I get 1 and 2 - which is correct

Comment: try this explode(',',$this->test())

Comment: Didn't work i get this following error
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): No such entity.

Comment: check which type of data getting in $this->test()  try this print_r($this->test())

Comment: I have updated it
How do I do the foreach